# Hosting a socket service in asp.net - issues with application_start & application_end

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, global-asax

We have a component that needs to sit in asp.net that creates a listening socket on a well known port. The reason we have the socket is the asp.net need component needs to received events from external services, and other technologies weren't quick or flexible enough.

We start the socket listening in application_start, and close the socket in application_end. The issue is if we are receiving http requests to the web site, and modify the web.config, the application_start event is called before the application_end is called, so we cannot open the socket (we get an error about duplicate socket being open). We dont have a reference to the original socket in the application_start after the web.config change, so we cannot shut it down from there.

Is there a work around to this ?

Cheers,

MrT

Answer (score 1):

How about obtaining a Mutex before listening starts, and releasing it after listening ends.  That way if the previous socket it still listening, the Mutex will block until the previous socket has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a faulty architecture.

Application_Start is executing before Application_End because IIS is starting up a new AppDomain for you, and will initiate it before putting it to use. It will also do this if you enable recycling of the application pool based on a time schedule or a number of requests.

It sounds like you want asp.net to do/manage stuff. I would try building a service that did whatever needs to be done, and update an application state (usually a database), and let your asp.net application read from that,

Answer (score 0):

Get your custom socket listening code out of asp.net.  Use a windows service to host this socket listener and you can have it call into asp.net as needed or the other way around.  Either way, you'll have a lot less trouble that way.

Comment: Theres not much choice for super fast entry into asp.net. Only asmx, wcf or msmq